# Excel VBA- Changing range format from R1C1 to A1

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook which uses VBA to create a pivot table. Currently, this is the section of code that I'm having issues with:

```
Sub TestMacroPieChart()
'
' TestMacroPieChart Macro
'

'

    Sheets.Add
    pivotWS = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sept 1 to Sept 30, 2019 - conta!R1C1:R531C9", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        pivotWS & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets(pivotWS).Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
```

In the section that I'm creating my pivot table, I would like to change my cell reference from R1C1:R531C9 to A1:H531. However, when I change my code to:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sept 1 to Sept 30, 2019 - conta!A1:H531", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        pivotWS & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
```

I receive this runtime error:

[image]

Could someone please point out what I'm missing? I'm still very new to using VBA.

Thank you!

Comment: `SourceData:= "'Sept 1 to Sept 30, 2019 - conta'!A1:H531"`  Sheet names with spaces need to be wrapped in `'`   And C9 is I not H

Comment: Could it be you need to change also `"!R3C1"` to A1 notation? Or maybe changing `Tablename`

Comment: Thank you for your input! `SourceData:= "'Sept 1 to Sept 30, 2019 - conta'!A1:H531" ` did the trick. I do have a followup question; I'd like to change the code to `SourceData:= "'Sept 1 to Sept 30, 2019 - conta'!A1:H" & lr `, where `lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row `, but I'm having an issue concatenating. Would you happen to know what the issue is?